# how to create AsyncTask object which is innerclass of MainActivity from another java class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am creating an application which fetches movies list from Tmdb Api.
My code is for main Activity is

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment { 
  public class FetchImageTask extends AsyncTask<...>{ 
    //
  }
}
```

And I have another adapter class

```
public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MovieImage> {

private static int page_nmber = 1;

public MovieAdapter(Context context, List<MovieImage> objects) {
    super(context, 0 , objects);
}

final String LOG_TAG = MovieAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(getCount() == position + 5 ){
        //Log.v(LOG_TAG, " last two images");
    }

    MovieImage movieImage = getItem(position);

    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_movie, parent, false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_movie_image);
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(movieImage.getImage_path())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
            .fit()
            .into(imageView);

    return rootView;
}

public void fetchExtraImages(){
    MainActivityFragment.FetchImageTask fetchImageTask;
    fetchImageTask = new MainActivityFragment.FetchImageTask();
    //Gives me error saying this is not an enclosing class
}
```

Actually I want to create another object for FetchImageTask object and call next page(page 2) 
results and append result to respective adapter.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: probably like `MainActivityFragment  objMainActivityFragment =new MainActivityFragment (); fetchImageTask =objMainActivityFragment.new FetchImageTask()`

Comment: `AsyncTask` does not have to be an inner class to work. You can use callbacks to have `AsyncTask` in a separate class file of its own, but to post its results anywhere.

Comment: See this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070716/instantiating-inner-class) that already answers your question, if you really want your AsyncTask to be a nested class, consider declaring it as static.

Comment: I think you need an interface to communicate between the activity and your fragment(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to not use an async task inside your activity.

1 - You could have to use the same task by another `class`,`activity` or `fragment`

2 - You activity will have single responsibility (SOLID)

3 - You can use `callbacks` to communicate to `activity`, `fragment` or any `class`.

Create an `interface` separated:

```
public interface FetchImageCallback{
   void onImageFetched(OBJECT);//replace by your 
}
```

Make your activity `implements` FetchImageCallback so you can get the images, ex:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment implements FetchImageCallback{

 public void fetchExtraImages(){
   FetchImageTask fetchImageTask = new FetchImageTask(this); //this is your callback
 }

 void onImageFetched(OBJECT){
     //do what you want to do with the images fetched (OBJECT)
 }
}
```

If you really want to use as inner class (not recommended) just declare `FetchImageTask` as static class:

```
public static class FetchImageTask{
  //some code
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have removed my Fetch Image Task as InnerClass and placed it as a saperate class. The result is passed via interface callback.(ie., listenerClass inside MainActivityFragment). It works fine. I have requested tmdb api to fetch movies lists.It returned just a single page ( having 20 movie entries ). I want to call FetchImageTask().execute() method in getView() method( overriden in custom Array Adapter ) for page 2. I 'm having problem with that

Comment: Finally I got it. I need to pass my MainActivityFragment innerclass( ie Interface listner ) to Adapter.                                                                         .........Thank you guys