# getConstructor() returning NoSuchMethodException when called by a Class type variable

Tags: java, getconstructor

I keep getting the following exception when using getConstructor() on a type Class variable:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Main$Person.()

The getConstructors() and getDeclaredConstructors() methods are working fine. I'm expecting the code to return: public Main$Person(Main)

**What would cause this and how can I prevent it?** Also, what is the 'Main' parameter listed in all of the constructors? Is this a reference to the instance that created it??

See code and output below:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Main{
    
    public class PersonSuper 
    {
        public int superage; 
        public void supersampleMethod(){} 
        private PersonSuper(){System.out.println("PersonSuper no argument constructor");} 
    }
    public class Person extends PersonSuper
    {
        public int age; 
        public void sampleMethod(String var){} 
        public void sampleMethod2(){}
        private  Person (int ageInput){this.age = ageInput;}
        public  Person(){}
    }

     public static void main(String []args) throws Exception{
         
        try { Class<Person> clss = Person.class;
        
        
            Constructor c[] = clss.getConstructors();
            for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
            {System.out.println(c[i]);}
            Constructor c2[] = clss.getDeclaredConstructors();
            System.out.println();
            for (int i = 0; i < c2.length; i++)
            {System.out.println(c2[i]);}
            System.out.println();
            Constructor con = clss.getConstructor(); //This is the code that is not working...
            System.out.println(con); //This is the code that is not working...
             
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {System.out.println(e.toString());}
     
     }
}
```

Results:
public Main$Person(Main)

public Main$Person(Main)
private Main$Person(Main,int)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Main$Person.()

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.

Comment: The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070716/instantiating-inner-class might be relevant because you are using nested classes and you can't create a `Person` object without a `Main` object, and `getConstructor()` knows that.

Comment: You're not providing the correct argument list. You're not providing any argument list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the outer class `Main` as an argument for the `getConstructor()` method when you have an inner, non-static class, as mentioned in the [`getConstructor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) documentation:

> [...] If this `Class` object represents an inner class declared in a non-static context, the formal parameter types include the explicit enclosing instance as the first parameter.

So you either write

```
Constructor con = clss.getConstructor(Main.class);
```

or make your test classes static (or put them in separated files anyway).

Comment: @ChrisC It would be `getConstructor(Main.class, int.class);` since the type of the argument is `int`. But the constructor has to be `public` as stated in the documentation of the `getConstructor()` method (or use `getDeclaredConstructor()`).